# BottomNavigationView text blinking on change

Tags: android, xml, selector, drawable, android-bottom-nav-view

Here is blinking:
http://gph.is/2GH9P0b

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation"
       style="@style/BottomNavigation"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="BottomNavigation">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@drawable/nav_bottom_selector</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@drawable/nav_bottom_text_selector</item>
</style>
```

Selectors `nav_bottom_text_selector` and `nav_bottom_selector`have the same code.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="#6e6e6e" />
```

MainActivity.class Here is tab change listener. But I do not think that problem is here because even I comment this part it is anyway blinking.

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_exercises:
                // even not replace tabs, just hide and show                          
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(exerciseFragment).hide(workoutFragment).hide(profileFragment).commit();
                SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().setLastTab(getApplicationContext(), ConsKeys.BOTTOM_TAB_EXERCISE);
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_workouts:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(exerciseFragment).show(workoutFragment).hide(profileFragment).commit();
                SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().setLastTab(getApplicationContext(), ConsKeys.BOTTOM_TAB_WORKOUTS);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(exerciseFragment).hide(workoutFragment).show(profileFragment).commit();
                //Saving last tab     
                SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().setLastTab(getApplicationContext(), ConsKeys.BOTTOM_TAB_PROFILE);


                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
    });
```

Navigation menu.xml for bottom navigation view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_exercises"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_exercises" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_workouts"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_workouts" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_profile" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Blinking of `TextView` usually means that you are constantly redrawing it. Can you add the code from your `Activity` where you are setting text to that `TextView`?

Comment: here you are, sorry for styling ,I am new here.

Comment: I am not setting text manually, it change automatically, from menu.xml

Comment: Now I saw your gif, and I am not sure what do you mean by blinking. It looks like a normal ripple effect.

Comment: As you can see from gif , Icon became white faster than text, and it look like blinking,

Comment: I just looked at your gif frame by fame, and I can't see it. But I am pretty sure that it's just a ripple effect. It depends on which part of the button you click first. If you click near the bottom, the text will first become white.

Comment: yes you are right its ripple effect, I just check it out.Ok thank you for helping ))

Comment: your GIF has expired

Answer (score 5):

This issue happens because of an API change introduced in Android Q that affected the transition used to animate the **BottomNavigationView** menu items. You've got two ways to fix it:

**FIRST:** Include this dependency in your app's graddle

```
implementation 'androidx.transition:transition:1.3.0-rc02'
```

This will replace the library's transition mechanism and the issue will go away.

**SECOND:** Lower your Target SDK Version to API 28 or lower. Although, I would only recommend this solution if the first one doesn't work, since you would loose any behavioral change introduced in the new version of the OS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This saved me. Thanks!!

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue :(